# (Family of) plane quartics with two double points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

The wikipedia page on plane quartics (http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_plane_curve) mentions the possible number of singularities that such a curve can have, including some examples.
I'd like to have an explicit example of a quartic having precisely two ordinary double points, or, if possible, a parametrization of an entire family of such curves. Any explicit examples or references would be appreciated.

Background: I am interested in elliptic curves occuring as desingularizations, and such quartics should yield examples by the genus formula. (I started by considering singular Weierstrass equations, but their normalizations are rational)

Comment: "A Guide to Plane Algebraic Curves" by Keith Kendig discusses the topic of intersection multiplicities in detail.

Answer (score 2):

This may be unsatisfying, but unless I have done something wrong,
$x^2 yz -xyz^2+x^4-2x^3z+x^2z^2+y^4$ gives one such example. My method was simply to force singularities at (0,0) and (1,0), which I did with all but the last term (expand out in terms of (x-1) to see why I did what I did), and then the last term was there to get rid of other singularities. Substituting $y^4$ with a general quartic term that doesn't mess up the singularities (e.g., $ky^4$ or a $y^3z$ term) should give you a family "most" of whose elements have two ordinary double points.

Answer (score 0):

By some chance this week I ran across precisely such a family, in the context of the following Diophantine problem: let $f(t)$, $g(t)$ be two quadratic polynomials (with rational coefficients, say). For how many rational values of $t$ are $f(t)$, $g(t)$ simultaneously square?

So: set $x^2 = f(t)$ and $y^2 = g(t)$. Eliminating $t$ gives a plane quartic in $x,y$, and this turns out to have two double points, both at infinity.

A few more details: say the leading coefficients of $f,g$ are $a,b$ respectively. Then $bx^2 - ay^2$ is linear in $t$; solving for $t$ and substituting into either $x^2 = f(t)$ or $y^2 = g(t)$ gives the desired quartic. Homogenizing and setting $z=0$ gives $(bx^2 - ay^2)^2 = 0$, and the two points at infinity $[\sqrt{a} :\pm \sqrt{b}:0]$ will turn out to be double points.

I suppose $(ax^2 - by^2)^2 = z^2 \cdot (\textrm{quadratic})$ will do the trick more generally.

Comment: Better still: see the Edwards Curve: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwards_curve